# Is the automatic comment for questions voted to be closed as duplicate not added anymore?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

The question [How should a date be written?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31946/how-should-a-date-be-written) is voted to be closed as duplicate of another question, but I don't see the usual comment being automatically added.

Are such comments not added anymore, or did the user who first voted to close that question delete the comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These comments are still added just as they have been.

The user who cast the first vote-to-close deleted the comment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got worried that the feature has been removed. `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the automatic comment because after I voted to close, I noticed that the new question included the day of the week as part of the formatting question. I didn't think the possible duplicate question addressed that, so I changed my mind about the vote to close.